# How do I forbid VS12 open projects created in previous versions (specifically 2008) and pop up conversion dialog?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, batch-file, visual-studio-2012

I have a big project that is known to compile fine in VS2008. It contains a lot of dependencies distributed in binaries so I decided that it's not an option to migrate to VS2012. I installed VS2008 Express specifically for this project. The project contains .bat script that picks up environment and then opens VS project. To my big surprise, even when I have VS2008 installed, VS2012 is started when I run that script. I digged into script and found out that it explicitly invokes VS2008 like this:
`start %MSVC_EXE% %SOLUTION%`, where `%MSVC_EXE%` is full path to VS2008 executable.

How can this happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's amusing, but I seem to got it. If you read `help start` you will notice that the first parameter is `[header]`, whatever it would mean. Then follow keys, then `[command] [args]`. So, if you look at the command above, you will notice that the first parameter is interpreted as "header", whereas solution file as a "command" that somehow caused this file to be opened as if I clicked on it with mouse. The solution is `start "" %MSVC_EXE% %SOLUTION%`. The syntax of the `start` command is clearly weird, causing it to do what most people would not expect.